# Proof of an identity verified by integer part function

Tags: functions, integers

Formula$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\lfloor{x+\dfrac{k}{n}}\rfloor=\lfloor nx \rfloor$$

where $\lfloor a \rfloor$ means the integer part function, sometimes called "floor" function (ex.: $\lfloor 3.4\rfloor=3).$

is one of the fundamental properties of integer part function.

I have to establish it but I have no idea of even how to start.

Can you help me ?

Comment: start by supposing $\frac{i}{n}\leq x-[x] < \frac{i+1}{n}$, then compute both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the change of variable $u=nx$, the desired identity is equivalent to showing

$$f(u)=\lfloor u\rfloor-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor u+k\over n\right\rfloor=0$$

for all $u$.

It's easy to see that $f(u)=0$ for $0\le u\lt1$.  But we also have

$$\begin{align}
f(u+1)&=\lfloor u+1\rfloor-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor u+1+k\over n\right\rfloor\\
&=\lfloor u+1\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor u+k\over n\right\rfloor\\
&=\lfloor u+1\rfloor-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor u+k\over n\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor u+0\over n\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor u+n\over n\right\rfloor\\
&=\lfloor u\rfloor+1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor u+k\over n\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor u\over n\right\rfloor-\left(\left\lfloor u\over n\right\rfloor+1\right)\\
&=\lfloor u\rfloor-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor u+k\over n\right\rfloor\\
&=f(u)
\end{align}$$

so the function $f$ is periodic with period $1$, hence simply repeats the constant value $0$ from the interval $0\le u\lt1$.